# How to troubleshoot PHP db insertion error I can't produce on my computer (accessed via a web page)

Tags: php, postgresql

I have some PHP on a page a form POSTs to for processing data and storing it in a Postgres RDS on AWS. Every time I have used the form, it has worked fine for me, but I have had two customers tell me their ratings were lost. The second database insertion and the email are always fine (so far as I know), but the first insertion doesn't always work.

I have not been able to reproduce this error on my computer with either Chrome or Firefox. Can someone recommend a way to troubleshoot this/reproduce the error and/or speculate as to what the error might be? Code is below.

```
$statement = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO cleanerrating (cleaner_id, appt_id, user_id, timely, effective, comments) VALUES (:contractor_id, :appt_id, :user_id, :timely, :effective, :comments)");
$statement->execute(array(':contractor_id'=>$arr['contractor_id'][0], ':appt_id'=>$appt_id, ':user_id'=>$user_id, ':timely'=>$timeliness, ':effective'=>$effectiveness, ':comments'=>$comments));

$statement = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO recur (recur, appt_id, user_id, created) VALUES(:recur, :appt_id, :user_id, 'now')");
$statement->execute(array(':recur'=>$recur, ':appt_id'=>$appt_id, ':user_id'=>$user_id));


if($user_id){
    include_once('email.php');
    $mail->addAddress('hello@loq-ly.com');
    $mail->AddBCC($alertEmail);
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "Received user rating for cleaning";
    $mail->Body = "We received a rating for cleaner ".$contractor_id." for appointment ".$appt_id." of effectiveness: ".$effectiveness." and timeliness ".$timeliness." with comments: ".$comments."<br><br>Recur value is: ".$recur;
    $mail->send();
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
```

Comment: Doing one insert, then another, is unreliable. It will error randomly. Make a stored procedure to do both inserts, with rollback on failure. Or insert to one table which has a trigger that populates the other. Or use a transaction and commit, rollback, etc.

Comment: Do you have any error logs?  That failed insert should be there,  Or at least a warning since you suggest it is not a fatal.  As for speculation... something is left blank, something is too long, something has values you did not expect... Probably `comments` field.  Improve logging or send all fields in the email so it is easy to reproduce.

Comment: @ficuscr Thanks for the advice. I do have logs, but I don't see anything for the file (rate.php) for the code above.

Comment: @developerwjk Thanks for the advice. This is a very low traffic site, so I thought I could get away with doing this. I will try the stored procedure idea.